# Setting the button text of a DataGridView cell button

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to insert and change a text of a button but it show as

[image: Display]

Here is my code

```
Button SaveButton  = new Button();
Button DeleteButton  = new Button()
SaveButton.Text = "Save";
DeleteButton.Text = "Delete";
object[] Data = 
{
  ProductList[i].ProductName,
  ProductList[i].ProductPrice.ToString(),
  ProductList[i].ProductCreationCost.ToString(),
  ProductList[i].ProductStock.ToString(),
  ProductList[i].ProductBarcode.ToString(),
  ProductList[i].ProductImageLoc.ToString(),
  SaveButton,
  DeleteButton,
};
ItemDataGrid.Rows.Add(Data);
```

I just want the button names to be "Save" and "Delete".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inserting SaveButton and DeleteButton objects into the array. Just insert the text property of buttons like below.

```
object[] Data = 
    {
        ProductList[i].ProductName,
        ProductList[i].ProductPrice.ToString(),
        ProductList[i].ProductCreationCost.ToString(),
        ProductList[i].ProductStock.ToString(),
        ProductList[i].ProductBarcode.ToString(),
        ProductList[i].ProductImageLoc.ToString(),
        SaveButton.Text,
        DeleteButton.Text,
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is about **setting the button text of a DataGridView cell button**.

The `UseColumnTextForButtonValue` and `Text` properties of `DataGridViewButtonColumn` are intended to be used for this purpose. A sample of some initialization code that sets the "**Save**" and "**Delete**" label for the buttons is shown below.

*This example uses the `DataSource` property of the `DataGridView` to attach a list of records where the `Record` class represents a row of data. This often makes things easier because you can work with the underlying data directly.*

[image: minimal sample]

---

The data source is a `BindingList<Product>` containing objects of a class you have defined to represent a row:

```
// Minimal product class for example
class Product
{
    // Read-only cells for this example.
    public string Name { get; internal set; }
    public double Price { get; internal set; }
    public string Barcode { get; internal set; } =
        $"*{Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 8).ToUpper()}*";
}
```

---

Then in the main form, the `Load` event can be used to set up the columns and formatting, including the **button text**.

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    initBarcodeFont();
    dataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
    dataGridView.DataSource = Products;
    dataGridView.RowTemplate.Height = 100;

    #region F O R M A T    C O L U M N S
    DataGridViewColumn col;
    Products.Add(new Product());

    // Format existing Name column
    dataGridView.Columns[nameof(Product.Name)].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;

    // Format existing Barcode column
    col = dataGridView.Columns[nameof(Product.Barcode)];
    col.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
    col.DefaultCellStyle.Font = _barcodeFont;

    // Format existing Price column
    col = dataGridView.Columns[nameof(Product.Price)];
    col.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
    col.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2";

    // Add the Save button column and format the button style.
    col = new DataGridViewButtonColumn{
        Text = "Save",
        UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true,
        Width = 90,
        FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat
    };
    col.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
    dataGridView.Columns.Add(col);

    // Add the Delete button column and format the button style.
    col = new DataGridViewButtonColumn
    {
        Text = "Delete",
        UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true,
        Width = 90,
        FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat
    };
    col.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
    dataGridView.Columns.Add(col);
    Products.Clear();
    #endregion F O R M A T    C O L U M N S

    // Add a few products
    Products.Add(new Product { Name = "Coffee", Price = 13.99 });
    Products.Add(new Product { Name = "Milk", Price = 5.49 });
    Products.Add(new Product { Name = "Eggs", Price = 4.29 });
}
BindingList<Product> Products = new BindingList<Product>();
```

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/product-list-00.git) sample.